# android ndk CDT build error for using OpenCV, OpenCL, OpenGL

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, eclipse-cdt

I'm developing real-time FaceDetection app.

originally, this app used OpenGL to read/write image and OpenCL for parallel process with JNI. and this app properly was operated.

currently, I want to import OpenCV for using several OpenCV functions and Mat data type. so, set up the OpenCV lib in my project.

however, this project cannot build .so file.

---

./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/JNIGLCL/JNIpr.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
C:/Users/CVLAB/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:367: undefined reference to`cv::Mat::deallocate()'
./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/JNIGLCL/JNIpr.o: In function `~Mat':
C:/Users/CVLAB/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:278: undefined reference to`cv::fastFree(void*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libJNIGLCL.so] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****

---

### OpenCV.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC

include C:/Users/CVLAB/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE     := JNIGLCL
LOCAL_CXXFLAGS   += -fno-exceptions
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     := -lGLESv2 -lEGL -ldl -llog -landroid -lOpenCL
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := JNIpr.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

I include OpenCV library.

property - Android - Library

I set the property - C/C++ General - Paths and Symbols - GNU C++
add this absolute path : 
C:/Users/CVLAB/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include

But, console print above error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lGLESv2 -lEGL -ldl -llog -landroid -lOpenCL
```

Comment: oh my God. T.T  Thank you very much. your advice is worth. 
I have been so painful by this problem for 2weeks.
I really appreiciate it. Thank you, Thank you.

Comment: You may as well accept the answer, if it works for you